# mysql ADDDATE issue updating record

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have the following sql statement:

```
start_time = ADDDATE(start_time, INTERVAL $minuteDelta MINUTE), 
end_time   = ADDDATE(end_time, INTERVAL $minuteDelta MINUTE)
```

`start_time` and `end_time` are both `time` fields in my database (not datetime)

`$minuteDelta` is 60 for argument's sake

Right now it doesn't throw an error but resets my time fields to 00:00:00.  Shouldn't this work?  ADDTIME doesn't work because it doesn't accept an interval which is what my jQuery plugin is giving me (an interval). start_time and end_time have some value like 14:00:00 let's say.

I have a similar statement where I'm adding days to a date and it works fine. What's my problem here folks?

**EDIT**

### Entire query

```
UPDATE events 
    SET start_date = DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 0 DAY), 
        end_date = DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 0 DAY), 
        start_time = ADDDATE(start_time, INTERVAL 60 MINUTE),
        end_time = ADDDATE(end_time, INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) 
    WHERE id='1'
```

Comment: I'm curious why you would be storing the date separate from the time?  You'd have a lot less calculation headaches and more querying flexibility if you stored them together.

Comment: You know... at first I didn't need the time, but I suppose that's irrelevant isn't it? I think you have a point.  Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$secondDelta = $minuteDelta * 60;

start_time = ADDTIME(start_time, SEC_TO_TIME($secondDelta)),
end_time = ADDTIME(end_time, SEC_TO_TIME($secondDelta))
```

Comment: This is produces the correct result but there's a typo in your answer. Remove the SELECT in both lines and it's good to go. Thanks @danielrsmith!

Comment: Good call, not sure why I put SELECT there in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `ADDDATE` requires a full date and time as a parameter, otherwise there is no context for the addition.  Passing just a `01:23:45` string/time value as the first parameter gives a warning ("truncated incorrect datetime value") and truncates it to NULL.  What happens if you have a time of '23:59:59' and try to add time to it?  It can roll over, but what's the context now?  Have you gained a day?  Does it reset to zero?  There's too much ambiguity in a calculation like that.

Anyhow, there doesn't seem to be a function that will produce what you want.  I think the closest you're looking at is [SEC_TO_TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) and [TIME_TO_SEC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec).  You can do something like this:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC('23:30:00') + 60);
-- returns 23:31:00
```

If you run into a rollover scenario here however, you end up with times greater than a 24 hour clock:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC('23:59:30') + 60);
-- returns 24:00:30
```

You could probably adjust for that with a rollover by subtracting 86400 from the result of SEC_TO_TIME if it was > 86400.  Something like this:

```
SELECT IF(
    TIME_TO_SEC('23:54:30') + 60 > 86400,
    SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC('23:54:30') + 60 - 86400),
    SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC('23:54:30') + 60)
);
```